# Getting place recommendations and list of people who like a place using FQL / Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-checkins, facebook-recommendations

Does anyone know if its possible to get a list of place recommendations and list of people who like a place (not only a number, but ids or names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook API wont tell you who likes a page, probably due to privacy concerns.  There also isn't currently an API for a list of places, although that is something they may and you could request [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).

Comment: I can get a list of places but what I'm looking for is a list of recommendations for each place. Currently I am able to get the checkin comments of friends for a place but this is not the same as actual recommendations.

Comment: You can get pages a friend likes if you prompt for friends_likes permission, but you can't look at a page/place and see who likes it.